# Can't load Facebook comments when loading content dynamically using Ajax/jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, facebook, facebook-comments, xfbml

I am having issues getting Facebook comments to load after adding them to a webpage using ajax.

Javascript Code:

```
    $().ready(function() {
            $(document).delegate(".image a", "click", function() {
                $("#dynamic-image").load($(this).attr("href"), {ajaxload:1}, function() {
                    $("#dynamic-image").css("display","block");

                    $('#dynamic-image').lightbox_me({
                        zIndex: 999,
                        centered: false,
                        modalCSS: {top: '10px'},
                        overlayCSS: {background: 'black', opacity: .9},
                        onLoad: function() { 
                            $("#dynamic-image").css("display","block");
                            FB.XFBML.parse(document.getElementById('ajax-fb-comments'));
                        },
                        onClose: function() {
                            $("#dynamic-image").css("display","none");
                        }
                    });
                });
                return false;
            });
        });
```

HTML5 Facebook comments code:

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="<? echo the_permalink(); ?>" data-width="627" data-num-posts="10" data-colorscheme="light" id="ajax-fb-comments"></div>
```

I have tried using both XFBML and HTML5 Facebook comment code and neither worked. I have used FB.XFBML.parse() before, I have it working fine with dynamically loaded like buttons however its having issues with the Facebook comments, they just don't load and there are no Javascript errors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got this to work.

All I had to do was use "FB.XFBML.parse()" and target the div that was around the fb comment tags.

Comment: This was beginning to make my brain bleed.  Thank you.